# extract string with linq

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there a nice way to extract part of a string with linq, example:
I have

```
string  s = "System.Collections.*";
```

or

```
string s2 = "System.Collections.Somethingelse.*";
```

my goal is to extract anything in the string without the last '**.***'

thankx I am using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way might be to use [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) followed by [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

```
int index = s.LastIndexOf('.');

string output = s.Substring(0, index);
```

Unless you have a specific requirement to use LINQ for learning purposes of course.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a regex instead. `(.*)\.\*`

Comment: Daniel I tried your regex but nothing changed. Maybe i did it wrong.

Comment: you should add additional \ to where appropriate, or if in C# use @ infront the string.

Answer (score 0):

With the regex:

```
string input="System.Collections.Somethingelse.*";
string output=Regex.Matches(input,@"\b.*\b").Value;
```

output is:

```
"System.Collections.Somethingelse"
```

(because "*" is not a word) although a simple

```
output=input.Replace(".*","");
```

would have worked :P